# Generate MSI with TFS build template + Advanced Installer

Tags: tfs, msbuild, windows-installer

I'm trying to get our Windows Forms project to generate an MSI installer using Advanced Installer, doing that on my own machine locally was simple enough. I'd created a new Advanced Installer project to the solution of our project.

However I'm now trying to get TFS to trigger a build of the MSI on our Build server next, and I'm not sure what's gone wrong with it.

We use TFS with Octopus for our Continuous Integration setup, and the project can successfully build on the server using our Build template. 
The TFS build once completed gets packaged by the Octopack plugin into a nuget package, and then gets copied to an appropriate folder: CD, DEV, TEST or UAT.

I have installed Advanced Installer in the default directory on the build server.
So using an existing build template as a starting point: 
Within the process section, I modified the 'Items to Build' property to include the new Advanced Installer MSI project (.aiproj file).

I then set a build output location within the Build Defaults section, so that I can see the files being compiled.

The result was that the first project builds ok and gets copied to the build output location complete with a log folder. Within the Activity log file, I get the error below:

```
Try to Compile the Project00:00:00

Compile the Project00:00:00

Convert Server Path to Local Path00:00:00

InputsInput: $/Care/Code/CareSafe Desktop/CareSafe-R4/careSafe.MSI/careSafe.MSI.aiproj
Workspace: 70_4_cda-mstfs1;USER\cda-service

OutputsResult: C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Sources\careSafe.MSI\careSafe.MSI.aiproj


If Build Outputs are Solution-Specific00:00:00

InputsCondition: True


Update Output Directory00:00:00


Set Solution-Specific Output Directory00:00:00

InputsValue: C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Binaries\careSafe.MSI

OutputsTo: C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Binaries\careSafe.MSI


If Output Directory Exists00:00:00

InputsCondition: False


Run MSBuild for Project00:00:00

InputsDeployOnBuild: False
NodeReuse: False
GenerateVSPropsFile: True
ToolPath: 
Verbosity: Diagnostic
ToolPlatform: X86
LogFileDropLocation: \\cda-mstfs1\tfsBuildDropLocation\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI_20160408.15\logs
Targets: 
RunCodeAnalysis: Never
CommandLineArguments: /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:RunOctoPack=true /t:Build /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToFileShare=\\cda-deployment1\deployment$. 
Platform: x86
LogFile: 
AllowUntrustedCertificate: False
DeployIisAppPath: 
MSDeployPublishMethod: 
ToolVersion: 
LogWarnings: True
CreatePackageOnPublish: False
MaxProcesses: 0
LogProjectNodes: True
MSDeployServiceUrl: 
ResponseFile: 
UserName: 
Project: C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Sources\careSafe.MSI\careSafe.MSI.aiproj
DeployTarget: 
Password: 
Configuration: Debug
OutDir: C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Binaries\careSafe.MSI
IgnoreDuplicateProjects: False
TargetsNotLogged: String[] Array
AdditionalVCOverrides: 


C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Sources\careSafe.MSI\careSafe.MSI.aiproj" /nr:False /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Sources\careSafe.MSI\careSafe.MSI.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=diagnostic" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:RunOctoPack=true /t:Build /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToFileShare=\\cda-deployment1\deployment$. /m /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Binaries\careSafe.MSI\\" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="x86" /p:RunCodeAnalysis="False" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\Builds\4\Care\CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI\Sources\careSafe.MSI\careSafe.MSI.aiproj.x86.Debug.vsprops" /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Diagnostic;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/8528;IgnoreDuplicateProjects=False;InformationNodeId=1569;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;LogProjectNodes=True;LogWarnings=True;TFSUrl=http://cda-mstfs1:8080/tfs/cordia;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Diagnostic;" /p:BuildId="c2d6b87e-a93b-4850-ab07-405fa6f74042,vstfs:///Build/Build/8528" /p:BuildLabel="CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI_20160408.15" /p:BuildTimestamp="Fri, 08 Apr 2016 13:56:06 GMT" /p:BuildSourceVersion="LCareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI_20160408.15@$/Care" /p:BuildDefinition="CareSafe Desktop R4 + MSI"


Handle Exception00:00:00


Set CompilationStatus to Failed00:00:00

InputsLabelName: 
SourceGetVersion: 
KeepForever: False
DropLocation: 
Status: None
LogLocation: 
BuildNumber: 
Quality: 
TestStatus: Unknown
CompilationStatus: Failed


If CreateWorkItem00:00:00

InputsCondition: False


Mark Requests for Retry00:00:00

InputsBehavior: DoNotBatch
Requests: IQueuedBuild[] Array
Force: False


Rethrow the exception so the build will stop
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue too and I got it fixed by explicitly using the 32-bit version of MSBuild. Advanced Installer extension for TFS is not compatible with MSBuild x64. So, you should make sure you edit your TFS build definition to have the [MSBuild Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647553(v=vs.100).aspx) parameter set to "x86" in case you didn't already do this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi  Herman, I did try this as well but I still get an error with MS Build. The specific exception doesn't seem to appear in the log but I will copy the relevant part into my original question so it's easer to see my configuration.

Comment: Hi Rusty, From the log file it seems it is still the Advanced Installer AIPROJ project which fails to build. Unfortunately, I have no other insight to share that you can try.